# How to initialize a service by calling a function from the service itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, initialization

I wrote a service. with a function inside it. Is it possible to initialize the service with that function? Have a look at this code.

```
app.factory('SidebarService',function(){
  var self = this;
  self.init();
  return{
    init : function(){
      alert("This is sidebar");
    }
  };

});
```

I tried to call the init by self.init();. But it is not working.

Pluker Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/gYw2VlneeUIJ7kHJF0Xz?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.factory('SidebarService',function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.init = function(){
        alert("This is sidebar");
    }  
    obj.init();
    return obj;  
});
```

<kbd>**[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5TFapd1JpWV2G4Rg5nxo?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `.service` instead.

```
app.service('SidebarService',function(){
    var self = this;
    this.init = function () {
        alert("This is sidebar");
    };
    self.init();
});
```

See updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gjaIudMZaVsKGxIHCYvr?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two ways to call inner method for factory:

```
fessmodule.factory('Data', [ function() {

    var inner = function(){
     console.log('in inner');    
    }

    inner();  

       var factory = {
            query: function () {
                 console.log('in query');                
            },
           newone: function(){
             return factory.query();
           },
           inners: function(){
             return inner();
           }
        }       

         factory.query();

        return factory;
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/773/)**</kbd>